# Vue + Express app on heroku not using the SPA in server/public folder

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, heroku

My app is running on heroku and the routes send me JSON files, but what I need is to use the SPA that is in my ./server/public folder as index.html.
When I open the heroku app it send me the JSON file that is sent from the "/" route, but I need it to use the Vue SPA, because of what I did in my front-end client if for some reason you go to a route that doesn't exists it does redirect me to my "/forum" route with the front-end client, but any other route that exists will not work, it will keep sending the JSON of that route.

app/server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const expressValidator = require("express-validator");
const flash = require('connect-flash');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cors = require("cors");
const config = require("./config/database");
if(process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production") require('dotenv').config();

mongoose.connect(config.database, { useNewUrlParser: true, useFindAndModify: false });

let db = mongoose.connection;

db.once("open", () => {
    console.log("Connected to MongoDB Atlas");
});

db.on("error", (err) => {
    console.log(err);
});

const app = express();

//Body-parser
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(cors());
app.use(expressValidator());
app.use(flash());
app.use(cors());

require("./passport")

//Routes
const home = require("./routes/home.js");
const forum = require('./routes/forum.js');
const ranking = require('./routes/ranking.js');
const profile = require('./routes/profile.js');

// Routing
app.use("/", home);
app.use("/forum", forum);
app.use("/profile", profile);
app.use("/ranking", ranking);

// Handle production build
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/'));
    app.get(/.*/, (req, res) => { res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html') });
}

// PORT
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server listening on port ${port}`)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are splitting the frontend and the backend with Vue and Express, you should probably build and host the Vue part statically and then have your Express running on Heroku.

[Here](https://appdividend.com/2018/04/14/how-to-deploy-nodejs-app-to-heroku/) is a guide on how to deploy your express app, and then you build and deploy your static Vue page, [here](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html#general-guidelines) are the docs for deploying Vue.

Comment: The front-end is already built staticaly in my express app it just isn't sending it. For example if you go to the home route it should send the index.html but it sends the JSON that is sent by the controller.